# Node mysql and promises

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a db module in my node worker. All I need is make it straight, without callbacks. query method still returns *undefined*. I suppose I did something very wrong in this piece of code but I have never seen the full implementation of promises in one place.

```
db: {
    init: function (parent) {
        var self = this;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['host'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            user: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['username'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            port: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['port'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            password: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['password'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            database: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['db'].replace(/"/g, '')
        });
        self._query = Q.nbind(self.__query, self);
    },
    query: function (query, params) {
        var self = this;
        return self._query(query, params).then(function (rows) {
            return rows;
        }).catch(function(err){
            return err;
        }).done();
    },
    __query: function (query, params) {
        var self = this, deferred;
        deferred = Q.defer();
        query = params ? mysql.format(query, params) : query;
        //console.log(query);
        self.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                }
                deferred.resolve(rows);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

**dump of deferred.promise**

Most likely that Q.nbind is not necessary here, anyway I dumped everything and deferred.promise is an object {state: 'pending'}. So my opinion the devil is in __query function.

**added**

```
query: function (query, params) {
    var self = this;
    return self._query(query, params).then(function (rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        return rows;
    }).catch(function(err){
        return err;
    }).done();
}
```

it puts rows to console, but doesn't return it. One guy claimed that such structure works:

```
function getKey(key) {
    return r.get(dbkey(key)).then(function(x) {
        return x && parseInt(x, 10);
    });
}
```

**added again**

Yes, removing done() makes sense. But it still returns {state: 'pending'}. May be the problem is in the way I am calling query?

```
test: function () {
    var self = this;
    var s = self.db.query(self.testQuery);
    console.log(s); // { state: 'pending' }
},
```

Comment: Two thoughts. First your query method looks like it is__query (2 underscores) while you are calling _query. Is that on purpose?  Second you are resolving the result from the query. Typically the response from a query is an object with a rows property so you may need to change that to deferred.resolve(rows.rows);

Comment: @GordonBockus, _query is promise returning function, built over __query, which returns promises. I think this wrapping is neccessary, but not sure. The second thought is fine but I put result to console, and got no object at all

Comment: Ah I see it now. Gotcha.

Comment: I think your latest code update has the problem of calling.done() on the promise to be returned. Remove the .done() and it should work as expected.  Also remember that when you call .query it returns a promise so to get the rows result you'll need to attach a .then handler

Comment: @GordonBockus, yeah, done() is the reason why it returned undefined. But now it shows state: 'pending'. (more details at very bootom of the question)

Comment: Yup. Remember you are returning a promise so your call should look like self.db.query(self.testQuery).then(function(result) { console.log(result);});

Comment: @GordonBockus, but if I want to use `rows = self.db.query(sql)` if there is a solution?

Comment: Nope. Not when calling an async function. Your result will either be handed to a callback or has to be a then handler for a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution

```
db: {
    init: function (parent) {
        var self = this;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['host'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            user: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['username'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            port: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['port'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            password: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['password'].replace(/"/g, ''),
            database: self.parent.cfg['mysql']['db'].replace(/"/g, '')
        });
    },
    query: function (query, params) {
        var self = this;
        return self._query(query, params).then(function (rows) {
            return rows;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return err;
        });
    },
    _query: function (query, params) {
        var self = this, deferred;
        deferred = Q.defer();
        query = params ? mysql.format(query, params) : query;
        //console.log(query);
        self.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                }
                deferred.resolve(rows);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

And how to call it:

```
test: function () {
    var self = this;

    Q.async(function*() {
        var s = yield self.db.query(self.testsql);
        console.log(s); // it is real rows
    })().done();
},
```

That is really powerful thing, you can write methods which returns promises and then use them all in one place you want:

```
Q.async(function*() {
    var device = yield self.modules.ami.device.get('123');
    var ext = yield self.modules.ami.extension.get('123');
})().done();
```

While the ami.device.get and ami.extension.get method returns db.query promises:

```
get: function(id){
    var self = this;
    id = parseInt(id);
    return self.top.db.query(self.select + "WHERE (`ami_device`.`id` = ?)", [id]);
}
```

I have to say thanks a lot to Gordon Bockus for help. This guy really saved me a day!

Comment: Good times glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you problem is how you are using Q.nbind. It is intended for functions that make a node style callback function(err, result ...
You are dealing with this in your __query function with the deferred. So I think you should just use __query directly and you will be in business. I'll post a code example when I'm back on my computer.

Comment: Look, please, at my latest edit. I think Q.nbind is not necessary, because query method returns clean deferred.promise object {state: 'pending'} without it. I am not familiar so close with node, I thought that node style is a spahgetti style, lol. Anyway, thanks for help, I'll try to rewrite in node style with err, res.